# Laying out all the relations in an n-dimensional array

Tags: algorithms

I have two types of objects: `M` and `N`, identifiable by a name. Additionally, multiple `M`s can be grouped into one or more `M-Group` (also identifiable by a name), same for `N`s. (If it makes your life easier, you can assume that nesting is not allowed, however nesting would be nice.)

A `Rule` consists of multiple `M`s and multiple `N`s. If I have a list of `Ms = [M(1), M(2), M(3)]` and a list of `Ns = [N(A), N(B), N(C)]`, I need to generate a list of rules that looks like this:

```
M=1, N=A
M=2, N=A
M=3, N=A
M=1, N=B
M=2, N=B
M=3, N=B
M=1, N=C
M=2, N=C
M=3, N=C
```

As multiple `M`s can be grouped into M-groups, assuming that our `Ms` list is condensed into a `M-Group` called `MG1`, then my list of text would look like this:

```
MG=MG1, N=A
MG=MG1, N=B
MG=MG1, N=C
```

If we group `Ns` in a similar way (`NG1`), then my list of rules would look like this:

```
MG=MG1, NG=NG1
```

Obviously this can be done pretty easily with two layers of `for` loops, but the added complexity of the user choosing to output the rules with groups instead of individual `M`s and `N`s means that I would need to check whether the user is using a group, therefore I would need to write 4 `if` blocks (one for `M-Group` -> `N`, one for `M` -> `N-Group`, one for both, and one for neither). If we add another dimension `O`, then I would need 16 `if` blocks to cater for all solutions, etc.

Is there is a solution that will allow me to generate this list without writing `2^n` `if` blocks (where `n` is the dimension in the array)?

(To those wondering: Yes, this is in the context of generating firewall access rules)

Comment: Fundamentally, it seems to me that you will want to code that handles a [variable number of dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4683760/471129), so you won't be using a fixed number of nested loops at all.

Comment: @ErikEidt Sometimes I forget that recursion is a thing. I'll have a look into that.